# How to avoid continuous clicking on image in JS/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have one image click function, once I start tapping on image continuously then multiple execution and malfunction is occurring. How to avoid it? Please help me anybody

Click event call
    $("#img").bind('click', level_2_buiding_1_Clicked);
Method

```
 function level_2_buiding_1_Clicked(e) {
//alert("Level2 1");
$(l_2_imgIdForClick_1).unbind('click');
$('#cashBar1, #cashBarDec1').unbind('click');
clickCount_1++;
if (clickCount_1 == 1) { 
    sold_1 = true;
    currPurRate_1 = counter_1;
    if (cash >= currPurRate_1) {
        if (localStorage.turnOffSound == "false") {
            purchaseSound("/android_asset/www/sound/sndBuy.mp3");
        }
        animate_1 = true;
        var imgId2 = $('#cashBar1');
        var imgId3 = $('#cashBarDec1');
        fadeIn_1(l_2_imgIdForClick_1, imgId2, imgId3);  
        document.getElementById('light').style.display = "block";

        cash = cash - currPurRate_1;
        document.getElementById('capital').innerHTML =  cash
                + "K";
    } else {
        clickCount_1 = 0;
        // alert("Can't purchase");
        $(l_2_imgIdForClick_1).auderoSmokeEffect({
            imagePath : "img/toomuch.png",
            speed : 3000,
            pause : "1000",
            repeat : 1
        });
    }
} else if (clickCount_1 == 2) {
    if (localStorage.turnOffSound == "false") {
        sellSound("/android_asset/www/sound/sndSell.mp3");
    }
    animate_1 = false;
    clickCount_1 = 0;
    sold_1 = false;
    currSaleRate_1 = counter_1;
    if (currPurRate_1 > currSaleRate_1) {
        $(l_2_imgIdForClick_1).auderoSmokeEffect({
            imagePath : "img/loss.png",
            speed : 3000,
            pause : "1000",
            repeat : 1
        });
        if (localStorage.turnOffSound == "false") {
            lossSound("/android_asset/www/sound/loss.mp3");
        }
        document.getElementById('dollar').style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById('dollar').style.left = screenWidth * x1 / 1024 +"px";
        document.getElementById('dollar').style.top = screenHeight * y1 / 720+"px";
        document.getElementById('dollar').style.width = screenWidth * 64 / 1024+"px";
        document.getElementById('dollar').style.height = screenHeight * 64 / 720+"px";
         $("#dollar").animate({left: lsX, top:lsY}, animTime, function(){
             document.getElementById('dollar').style.display = "none";
             //$("#pr").addClass('animated pulse');
                var properties = {
                         color : 'green'
                      };
                    var el = $('#ls');
                    el.pulse(properties, { pulses : 3 }); 
         });
        // alert("Loss");
        loss = currPurRate_1 - currSaleRate_1;
        document.getElementById('ls').innerHTML = loss + " K";  
    } else {
        if (localStorage.turnOffSound == "false") {
            profitSound("/android_asset/www/sound/profit.mp3");
        }
        $(l_2_imgIdForClick_1).auderoSmokeEffect({
            imagePath : "img/profit.png",
            speed : 3000,
            pause : "1000",
            repeat : 1
        });
        document.getElementById('dollar').style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById('dollar').style.left = screenWidth * x1 / 1024 +"px";
        document.getElementById('dollar').style.top = screenHeight * y1 / 720 + "px";
        document.getElementById('dollar').style.width = screenWidth * 64 / 1024+"px";
        document.getElementById('dollar').style.height = screenHeight * 64 / 720+"px";
        $("#dollar").animate({left: prX, top:prY}, animTime, function(){
             document.getElementById('dollar').style.display = "none";
             //$("#pr").addClass('animated pulse');
                var properties = {
                     color : 'green'
                  };
                var el = $('#pr');
                el.pulse(properties, { pulses : 3 }); 
         });
        // alert("Profit");
        pro = currSaleRate_1 - currPurRate_1; 
        document.getElementById('pr').innerHTML = pro + " K";
    }
    cash = cash + currSaleRate_1;
    clearInterval(cashCounter_1);
    document.getElementById('capital').innerHTML = cash + "K";
    document.getElementById('timer_1').style.display = "none";

    setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById('light').style.display = "none";
        l_2_imgId_1.style.display = "none";
        // alert("Sold");
        //alert("Arry No's "+fiveRandArr);
        var f = fiveRandArr.splice(0, 1);
        //alert("deleted in 2 :"+f);
        var uniqueNo = uniqueRandNo(fiveRandArr);
        //alert("Genereted unique no in 2 : "+uniqueNo);
        var a = fiveRandArr.splice(0, 0, uniqueNo);
        if(cash < 2500 && crossed_1 != true){
            initialRandamNoForRate_1 = randomFromTo(400, 550);  
        }else{
            initialRandamNoForRate_1 = randomFromTo(900, 1100); 
        }
        if (localStorage.turnOffSound == "false") {
            buildAppearSound("/android_asset/www/sound/build_appear.mp3");
        } 
        level_2_initialImgs_11(initialRandamNoForRate_1, uniqueNo);
    }, 200);
} 

e.stopImmediatePropagation();
$('#cashBar1, #cashBarDec1').bind('click', level_2_buiding_1_Clicked);
$(l_2_imgIdForClick_1).bind('click', level_2_buiding_1_Clicked);
}
```

Comment: How are we supposed to help you without seeing your code?

Comment: You might want to add what you actually execute

Comment: Please share some code. I would guess that you can solve it with a global boolean, or set the image as active, and check this before executing the malfunctioning code.

Comment: Added code please check

Answer (score 0):

You've got a JavaScript error: Too many brackets

```
function level_2_buiding_1_Clicked(e) {
    //alert("Level2 1");
    $(l_2_imgIdForClick_1).unbind('click');
    $('#cashBar1, #cashBarDec1').unbind('click');
    clickCount_1++;
    if (clickCount_1 == 1) { 
        sold_1 = true;
        currPurRate_1 = counter_1;
        if (cash >= currPurRate_1) {
            if (localStorage.turnOffSound == "false") {
                purchaseSound("/android_asset/www/sound/sndBuy.mp3");
            }
            animate_1 = true;
            var imgId2 = $('#cashBar1');
            var imgId3 = $('#cashBarDec1');
            fadeIn_1(l_2_imgIdForClick_1, imgId2, imgId3);  
            document.getElementById('light').style.display = "block";

            cash = cash - currPurRate_1;
            document.getElementById('capital').innerHTML = cash + "K";
        } else {
            clickCount_1 = 0;
            // alert("Can't purchase");
            $(l_2_imgIdForClick_1).auderoSmokeEffect({
                imagePath : "img/toomuch.png",
                speed : 3000,
                pause : "1000",
                repeat : 1
            });
        }
    } else if (clickCount_1 == 2) {
        if (localStorage.turnOffSound == "false") {
            sellSound("/android_asset/www/sound/sndSell.mp3");
        }
        animate_1 = false;
        clickCount_1 = 0;
        sold_1 = false;
        currSaleRate_1 = counter_1;
        if (currPurRate_1 > currSaleRate_1) {
            $(l_2_imgIdForClick_1).auderoSmokeEffect({
                imagePath : "img/loss.png",
                speed : 3000,
                pause : "1000",
                repeat : 1
            });
            if (localStorage.turnOffSound == "false") {
                lossSound("/android_asset/www/sound/loss.mp3");
            }
            document.getElementById('dollar').style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById('dollar').style.left = screenWidth * x1 / 1024 +"px";
            document.getElementById('dollar').style.top = screenHeight * y1 / 720+"px";
            document.getElementById('dollar').style.width = screenWidth * 64 / 1024+"px";
            document.getElementById('dollar').style.height = screenHeight * 64 / 720+"px";
            $("#dollar").animate({left: lsX, top:lsY}, animTime, function(){
                document.getElementById('dollar').style.display = "none";
                //$("#pr").addClass('animated pulse');
                var properties = {
                    color : 'green'
                };
                var el = $('#ls');
                el.pulse(properties, { pulses : 3 }); 
            });
            // alert("Loss");
        loss = currPurRate_1 - currSaleRate_1;
        document.getElementById('ls').innerHTML = loss + " K";  
    } else {
        if (localStorage.turnOffSound == "false") {
            profitSound("/android_asset/www/sound/profit.mp3");
        }
        $(l_2_imgIdForClick_1).auderoSmokeEffect({
            imagePath : "img/profit.png",
            speed : 3000,
            pause : "1000",
            repeat : 1
        });
        document.getElementById('dollar').style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById('dollar').style.left = screenWidth * x1 / 1024 +"px";
        document.getElementById('dollar').style.top = screenHeight * y1 / 720 + "px";
        document.getElementById('dollar').style.width = screenWidth * 64 / 1024+"px";
        document.getElementById('dollar').style.height = screenHeight * 64 / 720+"px";
        $("#dollar").animate({left: prX, top:prY}, animTime, function(){
            document.getElementById('dollar').style.display = "none";
            //$("#pr").addClass('animated pulse');
            var properties = {
                color : 'green'
            };
            var el = $('#pr');
            el.pulse(properties, { pulses : 3 }); 
        });
        // alert("Profit");
        pro = currSaleRate_1 - currPurRate_1; 
        document.getElementById('pr').innerHTML = pro + " K";
    }
    cash = cash + currSaleRate_1;
    clearInterval(cashCounter_1);
    document.getElementById('capital').innerHTML = cash + "K";
    document.getElementById('timer_1').style.display = "none";

    setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById('light').style.display = "none";
        l_2_imgId_1.style.display = "none";
        // alert("Sold");
        //alert("Arry No's "+fiveRandArr);
        var f = fiveRandArr.splice(0, 1);
        //alert("deleted in 2 :"+f);
        var uniqueNo = uniqueRandNo(fiveRandArr);
        //alert("Genereted unique no in 2 : "+uniqueNo);
        var a = fiveRandArr.splice(0, 0, uniqueNo);
        if(cash < 2500 && crossed_1 != true){
            initialRandamNoForRate_1 = randomFromTo(400, 550);  
        }else{
            initialRandamNoForRate_1 = randomFromTo(900, 1100); 
        }
        if (localStorage.turnOffSound == "false") {
            buildAppearSound("/android_asset/www/sound/build_appear.mp3");
        } 
        level_2_initialImgs_11(initialRandamNoForRate_1, uniqueNo);
    }, 200);
} 

    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    $('#cashBar1, #cashBarDec1').bind('click', level_2_buiding_1_Clicked);
    $(l_2_imgIdForClick_1).bind('click', level_2_buiding_1_Clicked);
}
```

In the code above

```
    }, 200);
}                           // <- this is an extra bracket 

    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    $('#cashBar1, #cashBarDec1').bind('click', level_2_buiding_1_Clicked);
    $(l_2_imgIdForClick_1).bind('click', level_2_buiding_1_Clicked);
}
```

Comment: Its bcoz of copy and paste.. Errors are not there but once I keep on tapping or hold tap for sometime malfunction is occurring